# C# IF / Console.Write need solution

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm trying to write out random numbers in an interval with IF command and use different color at each condition.

```
int x = -50, y = -38;
int min = 999, max = -999, sum = 0;

Random rnd = new Random();
int[,] t = new int[20, 20];
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        t[i, j] = rnd.Next(x, y);

        if (min > t[i, j])
            min = t[i, j];

        if (max < t[i, j])
            max = t[i, j];

        sum += t[i, j];

        if ( t[i, j] == min)
            if (t[i, j] == (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
        {
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
        }

        if (t[i, j] == (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
            if (t[i, j] == (min + 2.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
            }

        if (t[i, j] == (min + 2.0 * (max-min) / 5.0))
            if (t[i, j] == (min + 3.0*(max-min) / 5.0))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
            }

        if (t[i, j] == (min+ 3.0 *(max-min) / 5.0))
            if (t[i, j] == (min + 4.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
            }

        if (t[i, j] == (min + 4.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
            if (t[i, j] == max)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
            }
        Console.Write(" " + t[i, j]);

        //Console.Write("{2} ", i, j, t[i, j]);
    }
    x++;
    y++;
}
Console.WriteLine("Min: " + min);
Console.WriteLine("Max: " + max);
Console.WriteLine("Sum: " + sum / t.Length);
Console.ReadKey();
```

The running program only write out dark red numbers.

Comment: Please paste your code into your question. Indent it by one tab on the left margin so it will format correctly.

Comment: You didn't really describe what you *expect* to happen but if the dark red condition is satisfied, it will always use that one (since you didn't use `else if`). Could be your problem.

Comment: Your `if` conditions are strange. How can one and the same value `t[i, j]` be equal to 2 different values?

Comment: Set some breakpoints on the inside of your `if() { ... }` blocks. Your conditions look weird - probably not executing anything other than dark red.

Comment: Also, why are you putting your random values in an array? You're never re-using them, may as well use a local int. This is some of the weirdest code I've  seen lately.

Comment: I don't need to use the else.
The t[i, j ] is just a position and it should mean a number which is randomly generated.
I'll check the breakpoints again, but i don't think i messed that up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Mong Zhu's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40116247/80274) shows what is happening on the first loop. `t[i, j] == min == max` so

```
if (t[i, j] == (min + 4.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
     if (t[i, j] == max)
```

will always be evaluated to true because the function simplifies to

```
if (t[i, j] == (min + 4.0 * (0) / 5.0))
     if (t[i, j] == max)
```

Which further simplfies to

```
if (t[i, j] == (min + 0))
     if (t[i, j] == max)
```

And because on the first loop `t[i, j] == min == max` it further simplfies to

```
if (t[i, j] == t[i, j])
     if (t[i, j] == t[i, j])
```

Which will always be true.

On later loops `(max - min)` will not be 0. Because of that tests like

```
    if ( t[i, j] == min)
        if (t[i, j] == (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
```

Can never have both `if` statements be true because it is impossible for

```
min == (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0)
```

Unless `max - min` is 0.

What you likely wanted was to test greater than and less than. Here is a example doing that, I also will be combining your `if` statements in to a single statement and using `else if` as needed to make it easier to read.

(**UPDATE:** I removed the `t[i, j] >= min` and the `t[i, j] <= max` because that value can never be false. All numbers will always be equal to or greater than the minimum value or equal to or less than the max value)

```
for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
{
    t[i, j] = rnd.Next(x, y);

    if (min > t[i, j])
        min = t[i, j];

    if (max < t[i, j])
        max = t[i, j];

    sum += t[i, j];

    if ( t[i, j] < (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
    }
    else if (t[i, j] < (min + 2.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    }
    else if (t[i, j] < (min + 3.0*(max-min) / 5.0))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
    }
    else if (t[i, j] < (min + 4.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    }
    Console.Write(" " + t[i, j]);

    //Console.Write("{2} ", i, j, t[i, j]);
}
```

This does cause one change in behavior. Your first item will now be `DarkBlue` instead of `DarkRed`. If you want to keep the dark red behavior simply change the first if to

```
    if (min == max)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkRed;
    }
    else if ( t[i, j] < (min + 1.0 * (max - min) / 5.0))
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkBlue;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem is this:

When generating a random number between -38 and -50:

```
t[i, j] = rnd.Next(x, y);
```

These conditions become always `true`

```
if (min > t[i, j])
    min = t[i, j];

if (max < t[i, j])
    max = t[i, j];
```

and both values (`min` and `max`) get the same value!
Following from this all your further if conditions become `true` because you basically compare the value at `t[i, j]` with `min`, irrespective of the numbers you add

```
if (t[i, j] == (min + 2.0 * (max-min) / 5.0))
```

since `max`  and `min` have the same value you add always `0` so every condition is the same. and the last one is executed.

Comment: Note, this is what happens on the first loop. Every other loop after that I think the problem the OP has is once `max-min` is non zero none of the `if(t[i, j] == ...)` ever evaluate to true and it just uses the color it started the loop with (which was set to DarkRed on the first loop). I think he shold be using `>=` and `<` for the checks.

Comment: I was going to just leave it as a comment but decided I wanted to write up a full answer on it.